# Obtaining all data in a table with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm starting playing with **Hibernate** (version 4.3.11) and I want to obtain all entries in a table. What I'm currently doing is this:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
int listLength = query.list().size();
for (int i = 1; i <= listLength; i++) {
  products.add((Product) session.get(Product.class, i));
}
return products;
```

Is there a shorter way to obtain `products` from `query`?

Using directly `query.list()` I obtain a `List` while I would like a `List<Products>`

Comment: Yes, look at `Query.getResultList()`.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK thanks for your comment, I tried that too but my IDE gives me an error: `Cannot resolve method 'getResultList()' in 'Query'`. I added the version in the original post (4.3.11).

Comment: Why do you use so outdated version? Look at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select). Hibernate 5.4.10.Final allows you to do it in more elegant way.

Comment: @SternK I have a project that is using SQLite and I found a guide only with Hibernate 4. I tried then migrating to 5 but I didn't succeed. :(

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
List<Product> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
    for(final Object o : query.list()) {
        list.add((Product)o);
    }
```

or

```
Session session;
EntityManager em = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Product> query = em.createQuery("from Product", Product.class);
List<Product> list = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i try with the second approach I get an error in the first line: `Expected 1 arguments but found 2.`

Comment: Fixed second solution

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'getEntityManagerFactory()' in 'Session'`. I think this has to do with the fact that I'm using Hibernate 4 ?

Comment: Ye, because v.4. Do u have `EntityManager` in your app?